# Accessing NSManagedObject from background thread

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa, core-data

So I know `NSManagedObjects` are not thread safe, and the best way to get objects from a background thread is to use `[context objectWithId:id];` , and so pass around object ids instead of the actual object.

Let's say I have a global `NSManagedObject` in my `AppDelegate` (not the best design pattern, but just for example) `NSManagedObject *myObject;`

Is it safe to access this object's `objectId` from a background thread? Like this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
        objectId = appDelegate.myObject.objectId;
        //is this thread safe?
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not safe, since there's no guarantee that calling `objectID` on `myObject` is safe. You should access the objectID outside of your block (on the main thread, for example) and then use it within your block. Something like:

```
NSManagedObjectID *objectID = appDelegate.myObject.objectId;
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
    // use objectID here.
}
```

Comment: I agree with your solution, but I need to understand a thing,
objectID for a NSManagedObject is immutable property (after the first save). isnt it safe to access an immutable property from any thread?

Comment: @PushpRaj In general, having a property be immutable doesn't guarantee thread safety. For an NSManagedObject, the documentation is quite explicit that you should not pass NSManagedObjects from one thread to another, which is what the example code is doing (regardless of which properties you're accessing). You're right that the implementation details are *likely* to mean that it's safe to access objectID from a background thread, but it's certainly not guaranteed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a separate context for each thread that you use (historically).  Since dispatch_async is not guaranteed to run on any given thread, you will need to create a context inside the block.  Alternatively, on iOS 5.0 or above, NSManagedContext comes with new concurrency modes.  The context will create its own private serial queue for you to pass blocks to.  If you need to support iOS 4.x, then you could model after this behavior.  Create a serial queue, and only access the context from that queue.

You may not do anything that causes a query or change in a context from two different threads because it will possibly create a race condition.